# Collective Risk Model - Mixture Severity, Bernoulli Frequency

Tags: probability-distributions, actuarial-science

I have a "real life" problem.

I am modelling a form of Operational risk at a Company.
Each department of the company is asked for how a particular event will impact their department, in terms of cost.

Each department provides a "probability that the event occurs" (say, $p$). They then give an opinion of the severity of the event (amount of loss), given that the event has occurred, at different percentiles (the percentiles being $0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1$).

For this particular department, the frequency is modelled as $ N \sim Bin(1,p)$.
The severity, $X$, is modelled as a piecewise distribution; the CDF increases linearly between the given loss amounts.

I.e. the severity can be modelled as a mixture of continuous uniform distributions:

$F(x) = 0.5 * U(a,b) + 0.25*U(b,c) + 0.15*U(c,d) + 0.1*U(d,e)$

Where $U(a,b)$ is the CDF of a continuous uniform distirubtion with parameters $a, b$.
And the values $a, b, c, d, e$ are the severity amounts that the department has inputted.

This then implies an aggregate distribution $S_{1}$ for this department. For which the mean and variance can be calculated.

$\underline{\text{First Question}}$: What is the CDF of the aggregate distribution $S_{1}$?

Let's say that another department offers their view of how this event will affect them. They give a new "probability that the event occurs" (say, $q$).

They will also provide severities at the given percentiles. They will then have their own aggregate distribution $S_{2}$.

The way our modelling software works, we can only take one "probability of the event occuring". We take the higher of $q$ and $p$. Let's say this is $q$.

$\underline{\text{Second Question}}$: Is there a way to "edit" the severity distribution from the first department so that, given their probability is now $q$, the new, implied aggregate distribution is "as close as possible" to $S_{1}$?

Perhaps we can find the new values $a,b,c,d,e$ so that the 1st to 5th moments of $S_{1}$ are the same as the new aggregate distribution? I'm not sure how to do this - I can get as far as mean and variance.

I appreciate the second question is a little vague - I can clarify any point. I have also done some pre-lim calculations in Excel which I can provide (how do I attach this?). Thanks very much for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate distribution is a zero-inflated distribution proportional to the severity distribution, with the probability of no loss being equal to $1-p$; thus it has a mixed discrete-continuous density.  For the sake of simplicity, suppose the severity distribution is $\operatorname{Exponential}(\mu)$ and the frequency distribution is $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$; then the aggregate distribution is $$\Pr[S = 0] = 1-p, \quad f_S(s) = \frac{p}{\mu}e^{-s/\mu}, \quad s > 0;$$ alternatively we can characterize such a distribution by the CDF $$F_S(s) = 1 - pe^{-s/\mu}, \quad s \ge 0.$$  The same principle applies for other severity distributions.

This would also tell you that the answer to your second question is no, because if $q > p$, no choice of the parameters of $X$ will change $\Pr[S = 0]$.  If your belief that the true frequency probability is $\max(p_1, p_2, \ldots p_n)$ for all departments where the $i^{\rm th}$ department's estimate is $p_i$, then the attempt to modify the severity distribution to somehow "preserve" the aggregate is misguided, since that distribution is, by your construction, the probability of observing a loss of a given size, for a range of sizes.  Simply put, I don't see why you'd **need** to modify this.

Comment: Thanks heropup. I appreciate your comments - if I believe the true probability of the event occuring is different to a particular department's estimate, then so be it, that should be the estimate. However, in reality, the probability of occurence should be defined as "probability that both the event occurs and it impacts my particular department". This then allows each department estimate to be unique. The issue is the limitations of the model allowing only one probability estimate. I think the real question is defining what is meant by the "same" agg distribution, and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I now have an answer for my second question.

If the first department is to take the probability $q > p$, then one can just set the percentiles of the severity distribution from:

$0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 1$, to

$1-p/q, 1-0.5 * (p/q), 1-0.25*(p/q), 1-0.05*(p/q), 1$

(and maintain the same severity amounts).

The implied aggregate distribution in this case will have the same Mean and same Variance as the original distribution (perhaps someone can elaborate if further moments will match?)